# Should I use AKKA for the periodical task

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, akka

I have a terminal server monitor project. In the backend, I use the Spring MVC, MyBatis and PostgreSQL. Basically I query the session information from DB and send back to front-end and display it to users. But there is some large queries(like searching total users, total sessions, etc.), which slow down the system when user opens the website, So I want to do these queries as asynchronous tasks so the website could be opened fast rather than waiting for the query. Also, I would check terminal server state periodically from DB(every hour), and if terminal server fails or average load is too high, I would notifying admins. I do not know what should I use, maybe AKKA, or any other way to do these two jobs(1.do the large query asynchronously 2. do some periodical query)? Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Spring provides some support for async stuff - https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/ . For scheduled events you can use https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ . Or something like quartz-scheduler . You could also try Websockets so there will be a connection with the server for a long time and you can push messages (e.g. when your heavy query is done) to the client once they are ready.

Comment: @john Thanks so much! Some also told me that I do not need to async tasks maybe. If I could use scheduler to do heavy query every hour and store the data in cache(maybe redis or memcached) and fetch data from cache every time the user opens the website, the website would become fast, though the data may not be real-time. What do you think? Is this a good way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Spring and caching where necessary.

If the data you're displaying is not required to be "in real-time", but it can be "near real-time" you can read the data from the DB periodically and cache it. Your app then reads from the cache.

There's different approaches you can explore.
You can try to create a materialized view in PostgreSQL which will hold the statistic data you need. Depending on your requirements you have to see how to handle refresh intervals etc.

Another approach is to use application level cache - you can leverage Spring for that([Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache)). You can populate the cache on start up and refresh it as necessary.

The task that runs every hour can be implemented again leveraging Spring ([Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling)) `@Scheduled` annotation.

To answer your question - don't use Akka - you have all the tools necessary to achieve the task in the Spring ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks! If I am going to use Redis as a cache to store the results of heavy queries, actually I do not have any experience about redis or other cache before. So I guess I should use Jedis to store the results from periodical query(use Jedis like a second DB), and when user sends request to server, the backend would search in redis first, and if there is the data, return it. If there is no data for the request, go on to PostgreSQL and query like before. Am I right? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Akka is not very relevant here, it is for event-driven programming model which deals with concurrency issues to build highly scalable multithreaded applications.

You can use [Spring task scheduler](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) for running heavy queries periodically. If you want to keep it simple, you can solve your problem by simply storing the data like total users, total sessions etc, in the global application context. And periodically update this data from database using spring scheduler. You can also store the same in a separate database table, so that this data can be easily loaded at the initialization time.

I really don't see why you need "memcached", "materialized views", "Websockets" and other heavy technologies and frameworks, for a caching a small set of data. All you need is maintain a set of global parameters in your application context, keep them updated using a scheduled task as frequently as desired.